# setBackgroundDrawable with another view's background drawable selector breaks the selector states

Tags: android

If I set a Drawable object from Button.getBackground() on a button with a selector drawable and then call set setBackgroundDrawable on another button with that same drawable the selector states don't work.

Example:

```
//layout is inflated from XML

//buttonA object ref set from view
//buttonB object ref set from view

drawableA = buttonA.getBackground();
drawableB = buttonB.getBackground();
```

Now calling `buttonA.setBackgroundDrawable(drawableB)` will result in buttonA not animating correctly in the different selector states.

Am I doing something wrong? I tried calling getConstantState().newDrawable(getResources()).mutate() to make something like a copy of the drawable in case the state was bound to the original button but that didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just faced the same issue - so if anyone else finds their way to this dark corner of the internet, here is my solution...

```
buttonB.setBackground(buttonA.getBackground().getConstantState().newDrawable());
```

The states for both Views should now work. Hope this helps!